# Background App & Phone Awake/Asleep State

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, sdk, ios7

Does anyone know if it's possible for an app running in the background to know when the phone is in use vs. when it's asleep?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this using a public API, keep in mind the iOS app should have control only over its own behavior not the device's.

If are not planning to publish on AppStore, check below post:

[Detect screen on/off from iOS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191980/detect-screen-on-off-from-ios-service)