# Is it possible to track user activity in iDevice

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to track every activity of a user in their iPhone and display it?

For example - a user unlocks the iPhone (slide to unlock), then he makes a call and after that played a game, then opened the camera and toke a picture, after which they entered some reminder, and finally closed / locked the iPhone?

The challenge is to display all details when the user unlock their phone, locks their phone and other activity they have done in the iPhone.

[Example - user open a UITableView application where the tableview data is populated with those activity like the image below

[image: UITableView]

Comment: anybody if you are downvoting this question means you know where it is duplicated or where i can find the answer ... and if so plz share the link...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

**Luckily not**. You can listen to a very limited amount of device activities like locking or unlocking the device while your app is in foreground. Or when your app enters background or foreground again, etc. Basically a lot of things that happen while your app is active.

As soon as your app is in the background however you have no way of getting any information what the user is doing (except for reentering your app).

Comment: Thank you sir for reply sir..i will count that the app cannot be made. and if it is made it won't be accepted by apple..

Comment: @AbdulKarim yes, an app like that cannot be done without the usage of some private APIs and/or jailbreaks.

Answer (score 1):

Some of what you ask is possible, but it is not something you'll find without doing lots of your own research.

Device Lock State: [Detect screen on/off from iOS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191980/detect-screen-on-off-from-ios-service/14208787#14208787)

Foreground app: [how to determine which apps are background and which app is foreground on iOS by application id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by)

Some of the functionality will require the use of Private APIs, which isn't impossible to get onto the App Store, but you won't find methods on how to do that on Google.

Comment: At least I can show something Thank you, sir, thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for security reasons. And if it would work, Apple would never approve this app.

You should ask this question on a hacker forum. Not on SO