# Check Device screen On or Off in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, cfnotification

Helle there, I'm using the code below to check whether the device's screen is on or off. I got this code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066549/check-if-current-screen-is-on-or-off-in-ios).

**Code:**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), nil, displayStatusChanged, "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete", nil, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.deliverImmediately)
        //CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), nil, displayStatusChanged, "com.apple.springboard.lockstate", nil, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.deliverImmediately)

        return true
    }
}//AppDelegate class end here

func displayStatusChanged(center:CFNotificationCenter,observer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,name:CFString,object: UnsafeRawPointer?,userInfo:CFDictionary) -> Void {

}
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(CFNotificationCenter,
>   UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, CFString, UnsafeRawPointer?, CFDictionary)
>   -> Void' to expected argument type 'CFNotificationCallback!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<@convention(c)
>   (Optional, Optional,
>   Optional, Optional,
>   Optional) -> ()>')

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with the `displayStatusChanged` function? Any help, suggestions or link will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why is your `displayStatusChanged` sitting outside of your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfnotificationcallback):

- the `center` parameter should be optional (i.e. missing `?`),
- for `name` you have `CFString` but the documentation says `CFNotificationName?`
- and the `CFDictionary` should be optional (you're missing a `?`),

Should fix your error if you match your parameters to the expected types.

```
func displayStatusChanged(center: CFNotificationCenter?, observer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, name: CFNotificationName?, object: UnsafeRawPointer?, userInfo: CFDictionary?) -> Void {

}
```