# Can you track the amount of time you don't use your Android/iOS device?

Tags: android, ios

Is there a way to track the amount of time an individual doesn't use their cell phone?  For example, let's say I used my phone and decided to lock it (not use it for any given amount time).

Would there be a way to track this?  I've tried looking this up but came short.  My apologies in advance if this question seems a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't go into details, but on Android you can make a Service listening for broadcast events `SCREEN_ON` and `SCREEN_OFF`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off). You can then note the time between the events to figure out the amount of time the phone is on or off.

On iOS, I did a bit of research and it doesn't seem easily done. There already [a question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191980/detect-screen-on-off-from-ios-service) which also mentions how to do it on Android.

Comment: gotcha, thanks man.  have a good day.

Comment: In Android 8+ this broadcast no longer works.

Comment: I think this no longer works only when declared in the manifest, but it works for a service. Here's a one that does that from Google: https://github.com/google/physical-web/blob/master/android/PhysicalWeb/app/src/main/java/org/physical_web/physicalweb/ScreenListenerService.java

Comment: Yes you're right, but services in Android 8+ must be in foreground, which means permanent ongoing notification. And in most of cases the developer doesn't want a permanent foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

## For Android:

You can do so by registering a `broadcast receiver` to the following intent actions

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

and find out the elapsed time since the user last used his phone in the `onRecieve()` of the receiver.

This answer to a similar situation can be of help

[android: broadcast receiver for screen on and screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#answer-9478013)