# iOS: Check if the Phone is Locked

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to check if the phone is locked? Or do I receive a notification of the phone is going to be locked?

My app runs in the background, continues to play audio, so applicationWillResignActive: isn't really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, directly. Indirectly, [you can watch for accelerometer on/off notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone/7479052#7479052).

Why do you want to detect this event in the first place?

Comment: When the phone is locked the way AudioUnits handle the Audio playback is different, they expect more data per callback.  I would like my buffer scheme to be aware of this. - I knew this question had to be asked before I couldn't find it!

Comment: @TurqMage : Then why not just monitor the audio callback buffer size directly?  (It might change for other reasons than your app being put in the background.)

Answer (score 5):

Checkout UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable. This appears to be called when the device is locked. iOS4 + only.

UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

Comment: this is interesting, but I think the poster mean the "lock screen"

Comment: For completeness UIApplication also posts the `UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` notification and has the `protectedDataAvailable` property for determining the current state.

Comment: But protected data is only unavailable if the device is locked AND data protection is enabled. But what about if data protection is not enabled?