# View Controller method for lock button pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there an available view controller method that is called when the user presses the lock button?  I'm looking for something like `viewDidDisappear:` or `viewWillDisappear:`, but specific to the case of the lock button being pressed.

Comment: The phone call hold button?

Comment: What is this 'hold button' you speak of?

Comment: The button on the top right of the phone.

Comment: My mistake -- the "lock" button

Comment: Please edit your question with 'lock' instead of 'hold'

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Check if the Phone is Locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969252/ios-check-if-the-phone-is-locked)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14213968/77567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A notification called `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` is posted when the user locks their phone. Here's how to listen for it:

In `viewDidLoad:` of your ViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenLocked) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Then, define a method (mine was called `screenLocked` above) and write code you want to be executed when the screen is locked.

```
-(void)screenLocked{
    //do stuff
}
```

Also, to do some necessary cleanup, add this method to your ViewController too.

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
  if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
      NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
  } else if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
      NSLog(@"Sent to background by home button/switching to other app");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a method defined in the AppDelegate, and not a method of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was specifically looking for a method that would be called inside of a view controller. hw731's answer addresses this.