# iOS: Detect screen on/off events

Tags: ios, events, screen

I'm trying to detect screen on/off events from a background service on iOS.

Because my app is not necessarily in the foreground, looking for app lifecycle events such as this aren't any use:
[Lock Unlock events iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone)

The best solution I've got so far is to search through the system logs, looking for Springboard events. Problem is, it's a pretty expensive operation, and requires regular polling which is a waste of battery. The solution needs to work on non-jailbroken devices but doesn't necessarily need to be app-store approved.

Can anyone suggest something better?

Comment: You should explicitly state if you are looking for a jailbreak or an App Store solution.

Comment: Any luck? Wonder the same.

Comment: I've added an [answer to the question you linked to in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14213968/119114).  It uses the springboard events, but does not require searching through logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock Unlock events iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone)