# sleep mode vs notification center open

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, nsnotificationcenter

in both,
1) iPhone goes in Sleep mode
2) Open notification Center

It calls

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Is there any way to identify if this method is called because device went in to sleep mode or by opening notification center?

Comment: Why would you like to distinct these 2 behaviors? Tell something more about your requirement, maybe we can have some other solutions to your **real** problem.

Comment: Actually I've to load login screen again when the device goes in lock mode. And by any other way App goes in background then have to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some hacks to detect [lock/unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone/7479052#7479052), but nothing official that couldn't break with a future iOS release.

Answer (score 3):

OK, When you **lock your screen/iPhone goes to sleep mode**, the front most app(Your app) will **go to background mode**, and when you pull down the Notification Center, you app actually is not pushed to background.

So, you can use

`- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`

or

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

to set a value, say `bgFlag`, in your app delegate class,

then, when `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` is invoked, you check whether `bgFlag` is set or not.

Good luck.