# MPMoviePlayerViewController dismisses on screen-lock

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

After calling -

```
[self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewController];
```

The view dismisses itself after screen lock or backgrounding. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that locking the screen causes `MPMoviePlayerController` to stop, which causes `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to dismiss.

I ended up rolling my own custom `UIViewController` with `MPMoviePlayerController` taking up the entire view with full screen controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try below this post screen lock event in iphone sdk

[Lock Unlock events iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone)

after trying lock event to dismiss mpmovieplayerviewcontroller!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will be the natural behavior of the  device .. 
**Unless >>** you add the permission for it.

`Info.plist > Required background modes`

add mode **App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay**

Now difference will be that the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` will not dismiss, even after the app goes to background. But the video will pause.