# How to identify if a user has locked the screen in an iOS 5 app

Tags: ios, ios5

Our iOS app has its own passcode screen which is displayed to the user each time the application loads.

An additional requirement is that the passcode screen should be displayed if the user locks the screen. Initially I have used the applicationWillResignActive method within the app delegate to set the passcode view as a modal. I'm setting it on resign rather than applicationDidBecomeActive so that when iOS makes our app visible again you don't see a quick switch between views.

This works fine for when the user locks the screen but resignActive is also called when an SMS alert is recieved, which means that even if the user dismisses the notification they are asked to enter their passcode again.

Is there a way to work out if the screen has been locked, so I can respond specifically to that event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone/7479052#7479052

Comment: @janusfidel thanks for the link, I had previously come across that answer. I am just desperately hoping there is another way, perhaps specific to iOS 5?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am in the exact same situation now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Dave, I ended up using Nate's solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14213968/1219194