# How to open app on iPhone unlock

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I am trying to create an app that pops up like a second password screen every time the user unlocks the phone.

User unlocks phone -> custom security app opens -> custom security app closes and pushes user to home screen

Is this possible to capture the phone unlock event and open your app?

Thanks!

Comment: Not without jailbreaking; it would be a massive problem if installing an app could lock you out of your phone.

Comment: This post might be useful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely not. Third-party apps don’t get that amount of control over the system.