# Is there a message when the iPad is covered? I Want to mask the app for privacy purposes

Tags: ipad, events

Question: Is there a message/event fired when the iPad cover is flipped closed?
Purpose: I have an iPad app that collects private information, such that when someone enters the room, a user might flip the cover closed. It makes sense -- and a user has requested -- that the app close itself or otherwise mask the users information should someone else then pick up the iPad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone was suggesting to use the AppDelegate's applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidBecomeActive delegate methods and instantiate the accelerometer. When the device is locked (cover closed), the accelerometer is disabled and won't register events, but if the app is in the background, it's still active. Never tried it but it might work.

[Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone/7479052#7479052)