# iOS function to count when I check (open) my phone

Tags: ios, iphone

Does anyone know the API call to determine when the phone is opened (unlocked)? Similar to this app http://www.checkyapp.com/

Comment: An old answer, but it may get you on track: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone

Comment: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/GraphicsServices.framework