# iOS launch my app after screen unlocking

Tags: ios, lockscreen, iphone-privateapi

I want to launch my app after screen unlocking. I don't want to send it to AppStore, just for home use. Is it possible with private-api?

To launch app I can use custom url scheme, just need to catch unlock event.
I see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone) but it doesn't work when app is in background.

Answer (score 1):

Try to hook into this method in SBAwayController
SBLockScreenViewController -(void)finishUIUnlockFromSource:(int)

Comment: How to use it? It seems that it doesn't work with arm64.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that. but i think your app is designed for special use, maybe you can consider that make your device never go to sleep and make your app never quit

Comment: no, after unlocking user should chose some option and use other apps.