# How to get time interval since device was unlocked

Tags: ios

I've got an app which uses a pincode for security but I would like to be able to allow user to bypass if device had just been unlocked, say within last 60s. Is there away to determine this using official API calls?. Using IOS 7.1+

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock Unlock events iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone)

Comment: Thanks @Droppy. I've read those but some of the posts are quite old, a bit hacky & don't work if your app is suspended. Looks like there isn't any way yet of reliably working out the time since unlock.