# Want to detect when user unlock or lock the phone in my IOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsnotificationcenter, background-mode

I want to know how user interacts with his/her iphone while my app is in background . Is there any api or notification i will get if user locks or unlocks his/her iphone ?

Comment: pretty sure it's a no

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone 
Is this wrong method? Its actually working .....

Comment: The above link question is having an assumption :-  Assuming it's only possible for jailbroken devices, can you point me to the correct API. if you are working on jailbroken device, you yourself have answered your question. For non jailbroken device, it is not possible.

Comment: I have tested it on simulator , its working . I will check it on real device .... Are you sure ? Please check the notes in its comment ....it is written that this method is working on non-jail broken mobile.