# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!'

Tags: ios, swift, darwin

From using this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012201/6165231) I'm getting this error in swift 4.1, i.e `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!'`

```
var notify_token: Int
notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate", notify_token, DispatchQueue.main, { (_ token: Int) -> Void in 
    var state: UInt64 = UINT64_MAX
    notify_get_state(token, state)
    if state == 0 {
        print("unlock device")
    }
    else {
        print("lock device")
    }
```

How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: var notify_token: Int32 ?? check if this works for you 1

Comment: Yes its working, but now this comming: `Cannot convert value of type 'UInt64' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt64>!'` @Roshan

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
var notify_token: Int32

notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate", &notify_token, DispatchQueue.main, { (_ token: Int) -> Void in
    var state: UInt64 = UINT64_MAX
    notify_get_state(token, state)
    if state == 0 {
        print("unlock device")
    }
    else {
        print("lock device")
    }
}
```

Comment: now this `Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Void' to expected argument type 'notify_handler_t!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<(Int32) -> ()>')` comes.

Comment: now this `Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Void' to expected argument type 'notify_handler_t!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<(Int32) -> ()>')` comes.
And I changed `(_ token: Int)` to `(_ token: Int32)` and its working but,
 `var state: UInt64 = UINT64_MAX`
    `notify_get_state(token, state)`
`Cannot convert value of type 'UInt64' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt64>!'` this is appeared.

Comment: You have to give the address so something like this : `notify_get_state(token, &state)`

Comment: Well, I figured it out, Edit your Answer and put `var notify_token: Int32` before the function declaration. Then it will start working. Thanks